# OrientDB : Is it possible to maintain lucene spatial index availability during rebuild?

Tags: indexing, lucene, geolocation, orientdb, spatial-index

My Index :

`create index User.lat_lng on User (lat, lng) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE`

Orientdb [documentation](http://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Rebuild-Index.html) says : Query against the index skip the index and do a sequential scan when rebuilding an index :

`rebuild index User.lat_lng`

How I can maintain the index performance while rebuilding ?
Is there any tool that I can use to do this ? Should I consider using another searching method for the nearest neighbor search ?